# nHibernate many-to-many mapping delete association only

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, mapping, many-to-many

I've seen this question asked here but I haven't found one that is answered correctly.  I have a many-to-many mapping with these tables:

```
Collection
Items
Collection_Items
```

A **Collection** has many **Items** and an item can belong to many **Collections**.  **Collection_Items** is the joining table.

If (using **nHibernate**) I want to delete an **Item** or **Collection** and have it delete it's joining associations *without* also deleting it's children... how do I do that?

If you have an example it doesn't matter if it's XML or Fluent or attributes or whatever.

Also, I have foreign key constraints connecting the two tables to the joining table.

Any examples out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out I just needed **CascaseStyle.None** on both side and to remove the **Inverse = True** from the **Items** side.  Turns out this is a very simple mapping.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I needed. It works, thanks!